# why c++ stl priority_queue does not perform as efficiently as expected with customized compare functor

Tags: c++, stl, set, priority-queue

When I create a stl priority_queue with a customized compare function class, I find that it has very poor performance(It seems to have a O(n) complexity to push a element rather than O(logN)). But I test to use a stl set with the same compare function, the set runs much faster than priority_queue. Why this happened?

```
    //There are a lot of horizontal lines on x-axis. Each line is represeted by a pair<int,int> p, 
    //where p.first is the left point and p.second is the right point. 
    //For example, p(3,6) is a line with end points of 3 and 6.
    //a vector<pair<int,int>> lines represents all these lines.
    //
    //I would like to scan all the end points from left to right alone x-axis. 
    //I choose to use a struct end_point to represent each end point,
    //     struct end_point{
    //          int x_coor;  //the x coordinate of the end point;  
    //          int index;   //the index of the line, this end point belongs to, in vector lines.
    //     };

    //For example, if there are 3 lines on x-axis line1(1,10), line2(2,9) and line3(3,8), 
    //the vector of lines looks like vector<pair<int,int>> lines = [(1,10), (2,9), (3,8)];
    //And the 6 end points look like {1,0}, {10,0}, {2,1}, {9,1}, {3,2}, {8,2}
    //I want to sort these end points by comparing their x_coor(if equal, use index to identify different lines).

    //If I choose a priority_queue to sort them, it has a very poor performace(6000 μs to complete 1000 lines).
    //But I do the same thing(by using the same customized compare function class) on a set, 
    //it runs much faster(just 246 μs) than priority_queue.
    //
    //My question:
    //1.Why priority_queue perform so bad as to set in this example?
    //2.For the comparator function class, I introduce a variable count to record how many times the compare function is called totally.
    //but for priority_queue, it seems that each compare function would resume it to 0 without keeping it, while for the set, it could 
    //increase all the time as I expect. Is there any bug in my code(or that is the reason why there performed so differently)?

    //

    #include <iostream>
    #include <queue>
    #include <set>
    #include <chrono>

    using namespace std::chrono;


    //generate 1000 lines of [(0, 10000), (1, 9999), (2,9998),(3,9997).....(999, 9001)]
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> linesGenerator(){
        std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> lines;
        int lines_num = 1000;
        int length_range = 10000;

        for(int i = 0; i < lines_num; i++){
            int start = i;
            int end = length_range - i;

            lines.push_back(std::make_pair(start, end));
        }

        return lines;
    }

    struct end_point{
        int x_coor;  //the x coordinate of the end point;  
        int index;   //the index of the line, this end point belongs to, in vector lines.

        end_point(int x, int i):x_coor(x), index(i){}
    };

    //customized compare function class for priority_queue
    class pqCompare{
    public:
        //construct by keeping its own copy of lines.
        pqCompare(std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> &_lines){
            lines = _lines;
            count = 0; //use for count how many times the compare operation is called.
        }

        bool operator()(end_point ep1, end_point ep2){
            ++count; //increase by 1 if this function is called once.

            //std::cout<<"count:"<<count<<std::endl;

            if(ep1.x_coor != ep2.x_coor){
                return ep2.x_coor < ep1.x_coor;
            }

            return ep1.index > ep2.index;
        }


    private:
        std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> lines; 
        int count;
    };

    //customized compare function for set, almost same as priority_queue,
    //the difference is only because piroity_queue is a max_heap.
    class setCompare{
    public:
        setCompare(std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> &_lines){
            lines = _lines;
            count = 0;
        }

        bool operator()(end_point ep1, end_point ep2){
            ++count;

            //std::cout<<"count:"<<count<<std::endl;

            if(ep1.x_coor != ep2.x_coor){
                return ep1.x_coor < ep2.x_coor;
            }

            return ep1.index < ep2.index;
        }


    private:
        std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> lines;
        int count;
    };

    void test_pqueue()
    {
        //generate 1000 lines;  
        std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> lines = linesGenerator();

        //create a priority_queue with cmp as comparator.
        pqCompare cmp(lines);
        std::priority_queue<end_point, std::vector<end_point>, pqCompare> ct(cmp);

        auto tp0 = steady_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i){
            //for each line, there are 2 end points.
            int left_point = lines[i].first;
            int right_point = lines[i].second;

            ct.push(end_point(left_point, i));
            ct.push(end_point(right_point, i));
        }
        //std::cout<<"total count"<<cmp.getCount()<<"\n";
        auto tp1 = steady_clock::now();

        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << duration_cast<microseconds>(tp1-tp0).count() << " μs\n";
    }


    void test_set()
    {

        std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> lines = linesGenerator();
        setCompare cmp(lines);

        std::set<end_point, setCompare> ct(cmp);
        auto tp0 = steady_clock::now();

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i){
            int left_point = lines[i].first;
            int right_point = lines[i].second;

            ct.insert(end_point(left_point, i));
            ct.insert(end_point(right_point, i));
        }
        auto tp1 = steady_clock::now();

        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << duration_cast<microseconds>(tp1-tp0).count() << " μs\n";
    }


    int main()
    {
        test_pqueue();
        test_set();
    }
```

Comment: Fyi `for(int i = 0; i < 10000, i++)` isn't a valid for-loop. Perhaps post a *real* minimal, complete, verifiable example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using to compare your runtimes, but priority queue should win on this just on cache management alone. [See example **here**](http://ideone.com/PmYvpP). Please update your question with a full example like the one linked that produces your results, and include whatever mechanism and methods you used for measurement to fortify your conclusion.

Comment: I provide a example for my question. I think it should be more clear now. Could you help me for that?

Comment: Why do you need a copy of `lines` in your comparison operator? You are not using it. If you need heavy data in your comparison operator, keep a reference to it. A comparison operator is not supposed to be heavyweight. Changing it to const reference in both comarators fixes the performance issue. `void test_pqueue():37 μs; void test_set():384 μs`

Comment: 1.There is no need to have a copy of lines in this example. Probably I oversimplify it. In fact, each line also have another information(for example a weight value), that is why I want to keep lines in the compare class.

Comment: 2. I think the performance issue is due to different implementation of set and priority queue in stl. When I create my own copy constructor of compare class, I find that for p_que, it calls the copy constructor each time it needs to compare 2 element. But set does not. Therefore, for each comparison of p_que, it copies the whole vector of lines. That might be the reason.